# Deleting chars between a delimiter in a string

Tags: c++, string

I want to delete all characters between two same characters in a string. My function takes a string (by reference) and a char in its arguments.

Assuming that I used an `std::string` variable like this: `"hah haaah hah hello!"` as the first parameter and a char `'h'` as the second parameter, something like this should happen: `"hah haaah hah hello!" ===> "hh hh hh hello"`. As you can see, every character between two `h` characters has been removed. How do I achive something like this?

I've tried to use iterators and ended up with this:

```
void delete_chars_between(std::string& line, char del)
{
    std::string::iterator itr_from = std::find(line.begin(), line.end(), del);
    std::string::iterator itr_to = std::find(itr_from + 1, line.end(), del);

    while (true) {
        if(itr_to != line.end())
            line.erase(itr_from + 1, itr_to);

        itr_from = std::find(itr_to, line.end(), del);

        if (itr_from == line.end())
            break;

        itr_to = std::find(itr_from + 1, line.end(), del);

        if (itr_to == line.end())
            break;
    }
}
```

First, I search for the first occurrence of `del`, I store the iterator to its position in `itr_from`. After that, I search for the second occurrence of `del`. And finally I run a while loop that starts by erasing characters in a certain range if `itr_to` is valid. I repeat that over and over again while my iterators are not equal to `line.end()`.

But for some reason, this code doesn't work properly. It sometimes removes whitespaces and doesn't even touch the characters I was aiming to delete.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I wonder if [`std::regex_replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace) would be more appropriate here.

Comment: @NathanOliver, unfortunately I don't know how to use regex yet. I really want to achieve my goal without using it.

Comment: Maybe it is easier first to split your input by space in an array of strings like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c?

Comment: Iterators may be invalidated by `erase` try resetting both following the `erase` operation.

Comment: If you would treat input string as char array, you can simply go char by char over it, starting in copy mode, and for each char either copy it, or ignore it, to new empty string (append the char to it). If you encounter delimiter character, just switch between the modes (but append delimiter char anyway).

Answer (score 3):

`std::string` iterators are invalidated by all operations which modify the length of the string, so using `itr_from` and `itr_to` after the call to `line.erase` is Undefined Behaviour.

You need to use the return value of `erase`:

```
while (true) {
    if(itr_to != line.end())
        itr_to = line.erase(itr_from + 1, itr_to);

    itr_from = std::find(itr_to, line.end(), del);

    if (itr_from == line.end())
        break;

    itr_to = std::find(itr_from + 1, line.end(), del);

    if (itr_to == line.end())
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid undefined behavior you should reset both iterators before calling `erase`.

Looking at the expected output it seems that a closing delimiter shouldn't be used to start another interval:

```
"hh hh hh hello"  not  "hhhhhhhello"
   ^  ^  ^
```

So, this is my proposal:

```
void delete_chars_between(std::string& line, char del)
{
    std::string::iterator itr_from = std::find(line.begin(), line.end(), del);
    // I don't want to pass an iterator to two past the last element
    if ( itr_from == line.end() )
        return; 
    std::string::iterator itr_to = std::find(itr_from + 1, line.end(), del);
    //                                               ^^^^

    while ( itr_to != line.end() )
    {
        itr_to = line.erase(itr_from + 1, itr_to);

        itr_from = std::find(itr_to + 1, line.end(), del);
        // to start another couple ^^^^
        if (itr_from == line.end())
            break;

        itr_to = std::find(itr_from + 1, line.end(), del);
    }
}
```

Live example [HERE](https://ideone.com/MbphAa).